# How to avoid shrink error

Tags: oracle

I have 2 tables T1 and T2 with 500 million rows.

In T1 I deleted 200 million rows (T1 has function-based index)

In T2 I deleted 300 million rows

Now I'd like to know:

- Shall I make the shrink of the tables to free up space and improve performance?
- How can I shrink the table that has function-based index?
- How can I avoid getting the error: ORA-30036: unable to extend segment by x in UNDO tablespace?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Suggest you post here - http://dba.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Also, describe the function-based index. I've sometimes (not often, but sometimes) seen them used when they're not necessary.

Comment: deleting half the rows in a large table is a lot.  Do you have partitioning option?  Also, for this reset of HWM you may try a CTAS approach